# Which Drupal module allows donations combined with a field where donators can write a message?

Tags: drupal

I want to have donations on my [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) site and I would like to be able to display the top donators. Ideally, I would also like to have a field where they can write a message when they donate.

How can I achieve this? Is there any [contributed Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module) that already does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Implementing Donations

#### Using Commerce Donate

Use the [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) module to allow for donations for Drupal sites using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). Excerpt from its project page:

> provides a donation line item type along with a donation product and product display.
>
> In addition to being able to create a donation product, this module also provides a donation checkout pane, allowing customers to add a donation to their order as part of the checkout process.

Refer to this [tutorial/screencast](http://commerceguys.com/blog/using-custom-line-items-provide-donation-feature-drupal-commerce) for a great introduction to this module.

#### Using Commerce Customizable Products

[Donations using Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/node/2349203) details another approach, based on using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) also, together with the [Commerce Customizable Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> Drupal Commerce allows you to sell customizable products that require customer input when added to the cart. Use cases for this functionality include:
>
> - Business cards that require contact information and a logo upload.
> - Event registrations that require attendee information.
> - Donations the allow the customer to specify a donation amount.
>
> The core Line Item module accommodates these scenarios by letting you add any number of fields to the Product line item type and expose them to the Add to Cart form. However, sites that sell multiple types of customizable products or a mixture of customizable and non-customizable products need to define multiple line item types to handle the different configurations of fields. That's where this Customizable Products module comes in!

Refer to the [Commerce Customizable Products](https://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-customizable-products-screencast) screencast for a video walkthrough.

## Displaying top Donators

Some reporting related modules to pick from:

- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).
- [Commerce Reporting](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_reports).
- [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena).

## Field for donators to leave a message

Implement that field in a way that best fits your needs, e.g. via a field related to some content type.

Then use the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) modules to grant access to a donator after they completed the donation process.

For more details about this, refer to my answer to the question "[How to change fields permission using some action in the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159261/how-to-change-fields-permission-using-some-action-in-the-rules-module)".